# How to HIGHLIGHT a specific popup menu item?

Tags: delphi, menuitem, delphi-10.3-rio

I have this popup menu:

```
object pmTest: TPopupMenu
  OnPopup = pmTestPopup
  Left = 32
  Top = 24
  object mTest1: TMenuItem
    Caption = 'Test 1'
    OnClick = mTest1Click
  end
  object mTest2: TMenuItem
    Caption = 'Test 2'
    OnClick = mTest2Click
  end
end
```

After showing the popup menu with the `Popup` method, I need to programmatically HIGHLIGHT (not to click!) a specific menu item, so I tried this:

```
Winapi.Windows.HiliteMenuItem(pmTest.WindowHandle, pmTest.Handle, 1, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_HILITE);
```

But it does not work.

How can I programmatically HIGHLIGHT a specific popup menu item?

Comment: I don't know this function, but according to its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-hilitemenuitem), it "[a]dds or removes highlighting from an item in a menu bar". Your popup menu is not a menu bar.

Comment: So, How can I HIGHLIGHT a specific menu item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the [`TPopupMenu.WindowHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenu.WindowHandle) property is set to the [`Application.Handle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Handle) window, not to the [private `HWND`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.Window) that `TPopupMenu` actually uses internally to actually dispatch its `WM_COMMAND` messages to. That window is established when the [`TPopupMenu.Popup()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.Popup) method is called, and it does not update the `TPopupMenu.WindowHandle` property.

Try using the [`TPopupList.Window`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.Window) property instead of the `TPopupMenu.WindowHandle` property for the `HWND` to pass to `HiliteMenuItem()`.  There is a global [`PopupList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.PopupList) object in the `Vcl.Menus` unit:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.pmTestPopup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Winapi.Windows.HiliteMenuItem({pmTest.WindowHandle}PopupList.Window, pmTest.Handle, 1, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_HILITE);
end;
```

If that still does not work, then try the Win32 [`SetMenuItemInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfow) function instead, which does not take an `HWND` for input:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.pmTestPopup(Sender: TObject);
var
  mii: MENUITEMINFO;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@mii, sizeof(mii));
  mii.cbSize := sizeof(mii);
  mii.fMask := MIIM_STATE;
  mii.fState := MFS_HILITE;

  Winapi.Windows.SetMenuItemInfoW(pmTest.Handle, 1, True, mii);
end;
```

**UPDATE**: Upon further review, the `TPopupMenu.OnPopup` event is fired BEFORE the menu is made visible, and `TPopupMenu` may recreate the menu AFTER `OnPopup` has been called and BEFORE the menu is actually shown.  So, your best bet is likely to [subclass the `TPopupList` window](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=45678) so you can intercept the [`WM_ENTERMENULOOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-entermenuloop) message, then customize your menu items at that point.  For example:

```pascal
type
  TPopupListEx = class(TPopupList)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Msg = WM_ENTERMENULOOP) and (Message.WParam = 1) then
  begin
    // customize pmTest items as needed...
  end;
end;

initialization
  Popuplist.Free; //free the "default", "old" list
  PopupList := TPopupListEx.Create; //create the new one
  // The new PopupList will be freed by
  // finalization section of Menus unit.
end.
```

Comment: Please see the [delphi-praxis article](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2586-highlight-a-specific-popup-menu-item/): Now it works exactly as I want it!