# How to make Tpopupmenu to pre-select the 1st menu entry when a popup is opened with the keyboard

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

The items in TPopupMenu can be highlighted/selected with keyboard or mouse. When selected with keyboard, you can move in the menu with the arrow keys.

How to mark the 1st menu item as selected (blue) without simulating the down arrow keypress with VK_DOWN (see code below)?

```
Popup := TPopupMenu.create(nil);
Popup.OnPopup := PopupClick;
class procedure TTrayMain.PopupClick(Sender: TObject) ;
begin    
  // Code below activates the first menu entry.. 
  // Now Looking for an alternative solution to replace this hack:
  keybd_event( VK_DOWN, MapVirtualKey( VK_DOWN,0), 0, 0);
  keybd_event( VK_DOWN, MapVirtualKey( VK_DOWN,0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

end;
```

Comment: Since a `TPopupMenu` is simply a Win32 menu, your "actual" question is how to preselect an item in a Win32 menu. So it's a Windows question, not a Delphi question. (And the answer would be the same in a C app, a C++ app, etc.) Now, since the Win32 API has been one of the world's most used APIs since the 1990s, I'd imagine Google would give you many pages where this has been discussed in the past.

Comment: This does not seem to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850050/how-to-highlight-a-specific-popup-menu-item
  ZeroMemory(@mii, sizeof(mii));
  mii.cbSize := sizeof(mii);
  mii.fMask := MIIM_STATE;
  mii.fState := MFS_HILITE;
  SetMenuItemInfo(popup.Handle, 1, True, mii);

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I googled  and found this https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2586-highlight-a-specific-popup-menu-item/   but unfortunately the source code was not available any more.  Sorry if I am asking too weird Delphi questions here :)

Comment: @Tom which source code are you talking about? There are several downloads from within that thread and several links to e.g. StackOverflow. I can download each of the attached files without a problem.

Comment: @dummzeuch: Really? I cannot download any of the ZIP files. I get "Sorry, there is a problem
This attachment is not available. It may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it to this location.

Error code: 2C171/1"

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I just tried again: All three of them downloaded fine and I could open them with 7zip. But I guess that's because I am logged in in the forum.

Comment: As per the last posts in that topic the solution wasn't perfect either. The part "_not available_" in the website's error message must be taken literally: guests have no access permission. Sign up, then log in, then try again.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried to make an account to that delphipraxis.net for months but they do not seem to accept new accounts. Can someone copy the ZIP elsewhere if it really solves this Question,  or copy-paste the relevant code from there as an answer?

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet？

Comment: No, I am waiting for a solution (code) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the undocumented `MN_SELECITEM` message to the popupwindow.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Menus, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    Item1: TMenuItem;
    Item2: TMenuItem;
    Item3: TMenuItem;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  //To override the default PopupList, based on Remy Lebeau's code
  TPopupListEx = class(TPopupList)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const MN_SELECTITEM = $01E5;

{ TPopupListEx }

procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var hm:HMENU;

begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Msg = WM_ENTERMENULOOP) and (Message.WParam = 1) then
    begin
      //When the popupwindow is already created, we can ask it's handle
      hm:=FindWindow(PChar('#32768'),nil);
      //Send the MN_SELECTITEM message. The third parameter is the desired menuitem's index.
      SendMessage(hm,MN_SELECTITEM,0,0);
    end;
end;

initialization
  Popuplist.Free; //free the "default", "old" list
  PopupList := TPopupListEx.Create; //create the new one
  // The new PopupList will be freed by
  // finalization section of Menus unit.
end.
```

*Note about other (including the mentioned delphipraxis sample) solutions:*

*Setting the MenuItem to a highlight state with `SetMenuItemInfoW` or with `HiliteMenuItem` won't work, since it's only affect the appearance, but when you hover the mouse over any other item, the first item remains highlighted.*

Comment: Works as expected with D7 under Win7, but because of the simple `'#32768'` approach an already displayed popup menu (other program) will be controlled. Further checks are needed to ensure only the intended popup menu is issued.

Comment: It's very uncommon to have two popupmenus opened at the same time. It can be achieved only programatically by opening one when there is another open. Since the PopupMenu is attached to the Desktop's window handler, it can't be determined which one is "our". Maybe you can save a list of every other popupmenu's handler before it shown, then use the newly created handler only.

Comment: No: every program can at least display one popup menu. Having 3 programs, all with their own hotkey, I can easily pop them up and have f.e. 4 menus open parallely - this is not made up and happens in real life. [Demonstration](https://abload.de/img/fourpopup3tkya.gif)

Comment: - *"... it can't be determined which one is "our" ...."* - It can, by various means... You can get the menu handle from the window you found by sending a MN_GETHMENU and check against your popup's handle for instance. Or, instead of FindWindow, you can enumerate thread windows. Or you can use wm_enteridle to retrieve the menu window. I'd assume there would be other ways which I can't think of...

Comment: I'd expect a UI problem with the solution as the same as the described problem at the last paragraph for another solution. After the menu item is programmatically selected, any movement by mouse will cause the selection to be lost - which is a fair probability given that the OP seems to be asking about a menu popped from a system tray icon.

Comment: Excellent solution, good work!  Actually I know the content of my popupmenu, so could there be a simple check in this code to compare if the 1st entry in Popup matches "xyz". 
 This would prevent sending MN_SELECTITEM  to wrong other popups if these are open at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, what you say could be a proper way to check, but according to @SertacAkyuz it can be achieved with a perfect solution.

Comment: Well, to retrieve item text you first need to have the handle of the menu. Once you have the menu handle, you might as well check that against popup.handle and skip item querying. Which is what I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are stuck with faking input. I think you can `PostMessage` key down/up messages to `GetFocus`. That makes it at least a local hack instead of global. You might need a hook to catch the right message to trigger the hack.

Ideally this should be documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cc-faq-iemenubar) but sadly it's not. The only way to know for sure how Microsoft does it would be to debug Explorer in 98/2000/XP. The menu implementation on these systems in Explorer and Internet Explorer is a context menu dropped down from toolbar buttons, faking a menu bar.

Comment: Thanks, faking the keyboard input is not a preferred option, it can cause critical issues under some machines, your answer to use PostMessage and GetFocus is surely an interesting one.